# Issues running my first JSF 2 application

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jsf, jsf-2

I'm new to JSF and trying my first application in Eclipse.

**Tools**

- Eclipse neon
- Tomcat 8.5
- JSF 2

**web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
        version="3.0">
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>faces/home.xhtml</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>

   <!-- 
      FacesServlet is main servlet responsible to handle all request. 
      It acts as central controller.
      This servlet initializes the JSF components before the JSP is displayed.
   -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**faces-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">

</faces-config>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.javaserverfaces</groupId>
  <artifactId>JSF</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>JSF Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
         <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
         <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
         <version>2.1.7</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
         <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
         <version>2.1.7</version>
      </dependency>


      <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
       <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
       <version>1</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
       <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
       <version>1.0</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>JSF</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

**Bean**

```
package org.javaserverfaces.chapter03;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean(name="helloWorld", eager=true)
@RequestScoped
public class HelloWorld implements Serializable{

    public HelloWorld() {
        System.out.println("Hello World Started!");
    }

    public String getMessage(){
        return "Hello World!";
    }

}
```

**xhtml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/
xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
        xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
   <h:head>
      <title>JSF Tutorial!</title>
   </h:head>

   <h:body>

      <h4>#{helloWorld.getMessage()}</h4>
      <h:outputText id="helloMessage" value="#{helloWorld.getMessage()}"/>
   </h:body>
</html>
```

**Issue**

After I deploy to Tomcat server, I get empty page by using the following url: `http://localhost:8080/JSF/`. The page title of the `.xhtml` file is correct meaning that the correct file is executed, but the statement inside the file doesn't get executed.

I am not sure if I have to declare some statements in the **face-config.xml** file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try adding the following block inside your web.xml file: `<context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>` and as a server-mapping try leaving only this `<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>`

Comment: @500Servererror After adding them to web.xml, when i run the same url i get the following error instead of blank page :: HTTP Status 404 - /JSF/

Comment: You use jsf 2.2 namespaces while you actually use jsf 2.1. Do a 'view-source'  in the browser and read the duplicate